# for loop won't show results

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to solve this one problem. I think I am in the right direction but there is this strange error that I got. My task is to create a python function with 2 parameters: one list and the second one integer. This is my function name: `def fun(aList, broj):`. The parameter aList should be a list of float numbers and they have to be inserted by the user. The list needs to be sorted even if the user inserted them in a sorted order. After that the second parameter broj which is a integer needs to be placed in the aList list in order that it doesn't destroy the order.

This is how I did it  `if aList[i-1] <= broj and aList[i] >= broj: aList.insert(i,broj)`. Now when I test the program and put these parameters aList=[1,4,3] and broj=2 I get a infinite loop. Why?

Here is all of my code:

```py
    def fun(aList,broj):
        a=int(input("How many numbers do you want to put in the List? "))
        i=0
        while i<a:
            x=int(input("Insert number(broj): "))
            aList.append(x)
            i+=1
        aList.sort()
        i=1
        while i<len(aList):
            if aList[i-1] <= broj and aList[i] >= broj:
                aList.insert(i,broj)
            i+=1
        return aList
       
    
    k=2
    x=[]
    print(fun(x,k))
```

Comment: Did you try adding intermediate `print` commands to see where you loop, and with what values?

Comment: You said it should be a list of float, but you're using `int(input(...))` instead of `float(input(...))`

Comment: You should break out of the loop after you insert `broj`.

Comment: aList.insert(i,broj) keeps on inserting broj into aList so the length of aList grows by 1, so you are stuck in this while i<len(aList) loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting into an infinite loop because when you insert `broj` into the list, it becomes `aList[i]`. On the next iteration of the loop, this is `aList[i-1]`, so `aList[i-1] <= broj` is true because they're the same number. So you insert `broj` again, and this happens on every iteration.

You should break out of the loop after inserting `broj`, since there's no need to keep looking for more places to insert.

You can also use a `for` loop instead of `while`.

```
    for i in range(1, len(aList)):
        if aList[i-1] <= broj <= aList[i]:
            aList.insert(i,broj)
            break
    else:
        aList.append(broj)
    return aList
```

If you never find a place to insert `broj`, it must be larger than any of the numbers, so it should be appended if the loop completes without inserting.

You can test for a number in a range by chaining comparisons `aList[i-1] <= broj <= aList[i]`